# How to get the source file line number from the Style DOM object?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm new to JavaScript world. If you check in the Chrome browser's Developer tools the right pane of the Element tab, you'll find the 'Matched css rules' section, there is a source file name shown and for each applied css rule there is the line number shown.

My question is, which object properties of the HTML DOM can tell the line numbers (and the source file name) ? Thanks!

Comment: None.  The Chrome tools (and similar things in Firefox and IE) cheat because they've got access to browser internals.

Comment: so the only possible way is to write a css parser? That'll be difficult....

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire first ([0]) style sheet...

```
var a;
for (var i=0; i<document.stylesheets[0].cssRules.length; i++)
{
 a = document.stylesheets[0].cssRules[i]+'\n';
}

alert(a);
```

You should be able to alert a rule by a line number I imagine though that would be utterly useless, you'd want to reference an element instead and figure out what rule(s) applied to it instead.

More here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/externalcss3.shtml

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how the code you illustrated can tell the 'source code line number' of each rule? Thanks!